# Meteor js - how to hook into the 'rendered' event of a recursive template?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I've got a situation where I'm rendering a Handlebars partial recursively based on a Mongodb tree structure, something like this :

```
<template name='menu'>
    <ul class='menu'>
     {{#each topLevelChildren}}
        {{>menu-item}}
     {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>

<template name='menu-item'>
  <li>{{name}}
    {{#if listChildren.count}}
    <ul>
        {{#each listChildren}}
           {{>menu-item}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
    {{/if}}
  </li>
</template>
```

where the mongodb docs look like this :

```
{ _id : ObjectId("525eb7245359090f41b65106"),
  name : 'Foo',
  children : [  ObjectId("525eb60c5359090f41b65104"),   ObjectId("525eb6ca5359090f41b65105") ]
}
```

and listChildren just returns a cursor containing the full docs for each element in the children array of the parent.

I want to do a bit of jquery makeup on the rendered tree, but I can't seem to hook into the 'rendered' event for the entire tree, something like

```
Template.menu-completed.rendered = function(){
   // console.log('done!');
}
```

Trying this

```
Template.menu.rendered = function(){
    console.log($('menu li'));
}
```

Not only doesn't this return the right results (brackets filled with commas), it also freezes web inspector (but not the app...).
Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: What kind of makeup you're trying to do? In most cases, you could avoid this problem by either 1) applying the jquery improvements to each template separately, or 2) merging templates.

Comment: I need to find a specific anchor tag within the fully rendered template and add a class to it... and then add a class to each of its parents

Comment: Do you try to use a custom handlebars helper an execute some JQuery if the current item is the right one (the anchor owner)? take a look at this meteorite https://github.com/raix/Meteor-handlebar-helpers

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting problem :)

In the current version of Meteor (0.7.x) the `rendered` callback is called once when the template is first rendered, and then again once any partial inside the template is re-rendered. (This behavior will change when Meteor 0.8 - the `shark` branch or "Meteor UI" - lands.)

I've never tried doing things recursively, but it's going to be very hard to tell which callback you get is actually for the parent. One thing you might want to try is to start the recursive rendering in a template called `menu-parent` or something. That way, when the `rendered` callback is called for the first time (and as long as your data is loaded), you know the whole tree is rendered.

However, I suspect there might be a better way to do this. Generally, you should not be using jQuery to modify classes and attributes on DOM elements, as you'll confuse yourself as to what Meteor is doing and what jQuery is doing. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve with the following, and I'll update my answer?

> I need to find a specific anchor tag within the fully rendered template and add a class to it... and then add a class to each of its parents

Comment: thanks for a lovely reply andrew ! what i need to do is build a tree menu whose appearance adapts to the current url. so if the url is 'new york city' for example, then i need to find the anchor tag 'new_york_city' and then add a class to each of its parents all the way up : 'new_york', 'usa', 'north_america' (for example). the data i'm using is actually dynamic so i can't just render a static nested unordered list for the whole thing

Comment: i've been looking at the shark branch and it seems like i'll be able to change classes without re-rendering anything, which will just about make my problem disappear...

Comment: In that case try `meteor --release template-engine-preview-10.1` where `template-engine-preview-10.1` is the latest template-engine (shark) release found at https://github.com/meteor/meteor/releases and see if you can get the classes to work that way.

Comment: thanks andrew i really appreciate your advice - i've upvoted your reply but since we didn't really resolve the original question i think the bounty maybe isn't justified. you can pm me if you want to discuss.

Comment: @Petrov you can do whatever you want - there are no PMs on SO.

Comment: Andrew and Petrov, you can continue on chat.

Answer (score 1):

Petrov, your code actually works for me, with just some minor modification to the jquery part. But perhaps I'm misunderstanding. Here is what I did:

1. Created a brand new project.
2. Added your template in the .html with minor change: `<li><span class="name">{{name}}</span>`
3. Created a new collection List.
4. `Template.menu.topLevelChildren = function() { return List.find(); };`

Then I added this handler:

```js
Template.menu.rendered = function(e){
    $('.name').each(function(i, e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
}
```

Now, upon render, for instance when new data is inserted into the `List` collection, I get a printout on the console like this:

```html
<span class=​"name">​second​</span>​
<span class=​"name">​second2​</span>​
<span class=​"name">​second21​</span>​
<span class=​"name">​second22​</span>​
<span class=​"name">​third​</span>​
<span class=​"name">​third2​</span>​
<span class=​"name">​third21​</span>​
<span class=​"name">​third22​</span>​
<span class=​"name">​third​</span>​
<span class=​"name">​third2​</span>​
<span class=​"name">​third21​</span>​
<span class=​"name">​third22​</span>​
```

This is just a flat list of the tree elements I had added (where `second2` is nested in `second`, and `second2x` is nested in `second2`, etc.). So from what I understand you could just take the selection coming back from jquery and find the tag you are looking for and change its class, as you wanted. Please let me know if I misunderstood something.

Complete code below.

---

test.html:

```html
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> menu }}
</body>

<template name='menu'>
    <ul class='menu'>
     {{#each topLevelChildren}}
        {{>menu-item}}
     {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>

<template name='menu-item'>
  <li><span class="name">{{name}}</span>
    <ul>
    {{#each children}}
    {{>menu-item}}
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </li>
</template>
```

test.js:

```js
List = new Meteor.Collection("List");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.menu.topLevelChildren = function() {
        return List.find();
    };

    Template.menu.rendered = function(e){
        $('.name').each(function(i, e) {
            console.log(e);
        });
    }
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

Comment: @Petrov: does this answer your question? Or were you also wondering about the jquery part?

Comment: @Petrov: you had a bounty which suggested to people that you really cared to get some help here. I would appreciate if you at least let us know how you eventually solved the problem and why none of the suggested solutions worked for you.